# Magento2 - how to configure a widget calendar?

Tags: magento2, widget, calendar

How to configure a widget calendar ?

I found some solutions, but can not understand clearly 
[How to add calendar in admin configuration options?](http://www.magewallet.com/magento-2/magento-2-add-calendar-admin-configuration-options/)

Can anyone review and guide me step by step please ?

Answer (score 1):

I created calendar.js in new mymodule:

```
   require([
            "jquery",
            "mage/calendar"
    ], function($){
   $("#period_date_start").calendar({
      dateFormat: "M/d/yy",
      showsTime: true,
      timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
      sideBySide: true,
      closeText: "Done",
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#period_date_end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
   });

    $("#period_date_end").calendar({
      dateFormat: "M/d/yy",
      showsTime: true,
      timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
      sideBySide: true,
      closeText: "Done",
      selectOtherMonths: true, 
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#period_date_start" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
   });

});
```

Comment: It worked for me, but can not save time(only save date). Anyone know why?

Comment: I debugged and saw this message: "6
TypeError: tmptime is null
 

tmptime = tmptime.replace(/(?:HH?|hh?|mm?|ss?|[tT]{1,2}|[zZ]|[lc]|'.*?')/g, func..."

Comment: when time is not saved and date show 2194-4-5 12:00:00 wheni post todays date